# Screen sharing via SSH tunnel on OS X

Tags: macos, vnc, ssh-tunnel

I have two desktop machines which I would like to do screen sharing (vnc connection) with (Machine A -> Machine C). 
But I would like to connect via a SSH tunnel on Machine B.

How can I do this? Both machines are OS X Mavericks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you want to share the screen on Machine A with Machine C, going through Machine B because A and C can't connect together directly. You need to forward the VNC port from B to A to allow VNC clients on B to connect. On Machine A, run:

```
ssh -R 5900:localhost:5900 $MACHINE_B
```

This makes it so that connections to the VNC port on B are forward to A. On machine C run:

```
ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 $MACHINE_B
```

This makes it so that connections to the VNC port on C are forward to B, and then onwards to A.

5900 is the most likely possibility for the VNC port, but your VNC server may choose a different port. Check its output when starting.

Comment: So according to Machine A, I'm VNC'ing into Machine B? (which is actually forwarding it to Machine C).

Comment: C is actually connecting to A in my example. The language SSH uses is confusing, when we forward a port from B to A, we are making a server on A available on B. We tell the VNC client to connect to localhost, so Machine C think it is connecting to itself, when really it is running through two SSH tunnels to A.

Comment: Does this mean the connections on both sides are encrypted? If it effects speed I only need to have an encrypted connection from machine A to B. Machine B will be hosted locally with Machine C so encryption won't be needed

Comment: Yes, both sides will be encrypted. Encryption doesn't usually have a significant influence on speed, the compression/decompression needed for VNC will take up far more CPU time. If you want to squeeze out that last bit of speed, you can have the port on Machine B opened to your internal network, but I don't recommend putting in the effort.